# CRTP and alternative

Tags: c++

I learned [CRTP](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/crtp) a while ago. Using non-virtual functions can be really helpful. A typical implementation looks like this:

```
template <class Derived>
struct Base { void name() { (static_cast<Derived*>(this))->impl(); } };
struct D1 : public Base<D1> { void impl() { std::puts("D1::impl()"); } };
struct D2 : public Base<D2> { void impl() { std::puts("D2::impl()"); } };

// Base<D1> b1; b1.name(); //undefined behavior
// Base<D2> b2; b2.name(); //undefined behavior
D1 d1; d1.name();
D2 d2; d2.name();
```

Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/static-cast-operator?view=msvc-170) tells that `static_cast` can be unsafe:

> However, static_cast relies exclusively on the information provided in the cast statement and can therefore be unsafe.

So, I thought about the following implementation of static polymorphism for an interface implementation:

```
template <typename T>
struct Base 
{ 
private: 
 T t;
public:
void name() { t.nameImpl(); } 
};
struct D1 { void nameImpl() { std::puts("D1::impl()"); } };
struct D2 { };
```

Creating/using an object goes like this:

```
Base<D1> obj;
Base.name();

Base<D2> obj2; //error
```

Is there a name for this implementation/pattern? Are there any drawbacks/benefits?

Comment: This is simple containment. It doesn't seem to have any special features of CRTP.

Comment: what are the benefits of crtp of this "Container"(?)?

Comment: The magic of CRTP is in these properties: (1) derived can use methods from base (2) base can use methods from derived (3) there are no virtual functions (4) there are no pointers from base to derived or back. If you don't have any one of those properties, then there is no improvement over CRTP. This doesn't mean what you have is bad. If it works for your purposes, great.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! you seem to know crtp quite well. so i have question regarding the crtp undefined behavior. Cpprefernce tells me that using an object Base<D1> is undefined behavior (as in first example). can u confirm that? So my implemtation is basicly a Wrapper to force a specific interface?

Comment: Static cast *can* be unsafe. It is not *always* unsafe. Static cast as used by CRTP is safe.

Comment: If your concern with CRTP is the danger of creating Base objects,then you can prevent it by making Base constructor protected.

Comment: An alternative to CRTP is the new "deducing this" feature in C++23: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp23-deducing-this/: "*... a bunch of additional features fall out of this almost by magic. These include ... a version of the CRTP which doesn’t require the base class to be templated on the derived class.*"

Comment: `static_cast` is absolutely safe when casting from a derived class pointer to a base class pointer. That's what CRTP is doing.

Comment: @MarkRansom I think you mean the other way around: "*... when casting from a **base class** pointer to a **derived class** pointer*".  No cast is needed when going the other way.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I meant what I said, but it's been a long time since I used CRTP, maybe I'm a bit confused on the details.

Comment: @MarkRansom CRTP is always implemented in the base class, so `this` is a base class pointer that gets casted to a derived class to access members that are in that derived class and not in the base class.

Comment: thanks for all the answers :). @Remy Lebau i read the post you have send. sadly i have no c++23 compiler available for my platform. So if i can cast the this pointer to derived class safely, why is using "Base<D1> obj" undefined behavior (as cpprefernce's example tells)

Comment: @gDator in the cppreference example, `Base<D1> b1; b1.name();` causes UB because it is not creating an instance of `D1` but `name()` is casting its `this` pointer (ie `Base*`) to `D1*` and thus calls `D1::impl()` on an object that is not a `D1` instance.

Comment: I understand. So creating a baseclass object should be forbidden as suggested by @Eugene. If i run the example it works anyway?!

Comment: It is not forbidden automatically. You must have Base constructors protected to forbid it.

Comment: There are two distinct uses of inheritance relationships: a) being able to access derived objects from different derived classes all as pointer to base object. E.g. for storing pointers into a container or using a base type as parameter for functions. b) to reuse code. - With CRTP and the bases being templated (thus actually being different classes) only b) remains. All the derived classes (or the base class) would have to inherit from another class to also provide a) and a common interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As illustrated in the examples in the Microsoft article the "danger" they refer to is to cast a `Base*` to a `Derived*` when then pointer is not actually pointing to a `Derived` instance.

In other words, `Base<D1> b1` by itself is useless but ok. Then `b1.name()` casts a `Base*` to a `Derived*` and tries to call method the object doesn't actually have. Undefined behavior is invoked.

As mentioend in comments this issue can be mitigated by making `Base` constructor protected:

```
template <class Derived>
struct Base { 
    void name() { (static_cast<Derived*>(this))->impl(); } 
    protected:
    Base() = default;
};
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/P7nj1reoW)

What you suggest as alternative is just composition. To see what CRTP can do rather easily I refer you to the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)  that comes with some concrete examples.

Comment: Sadly i cant vote up. But thank you very much

Comment: @gDator But you can accept as answer (it is independent of voting up)